# Custom Iterator not Working

Tags: class

```
public with sharing class CustomListIterator

{

        list<integer>num = new list<integer>{1,2,3,4,5,6};

        iterator numIterator = num.iterator();

        while(numIterator.hasNext())

        {

             system.debug(numIterator.next());

        }
}
```

This Code gave an error and not save.

> Error: Compile Error: expecting right curly bracket, found 'while' at
>   line 5 column 4

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Error: Compile Error: expecting right curly bracket, found 'while' at line 5 column 4

Comment: change this `iterator numIterator = num.iterator();`  into `iterator<Integer> numIterator = num.iterator();`

Comment: and this is complete class code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your code inside a method inorder to avoid that error.You are directly wrote the code inside class.

```
public with sharing class CustomListIterator{

  public void method_name(){

    list<integer>num = new list<integer>{1,2,3,4,5,6};

        iterator<integer> numIterator = num.iterator();

        while(numIterator.hasNext())

        {
             system.debug(numIterator.next());
        }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]You need to mention type for iterator.

```
List<integer> num = new List<integer>{1,2,3,4,5,6};
Iterator<Integer> numIterator = num.iterator();

while(numIterator.hasNext()){
   system.debug(numIterator.next());
}
```

This is working now. Hope this helps.

Added screenshot.

Comment: Thanks Kiran.But already tried this gave same error.